Prove that if $G$ contains a cycle then $g \leq 2d+1$
Currently reading graph theory by Diestel. The proposition states the following

Proposition 1.3.2. Every graph $G$ containing a cycle satisfies $g(G) \leq 2\text{diam}(G)+1$

Any corrections to my reasoning is appreciated. My sketch so far:
For ease of notation let $g(G)=g$ and $\text{diam}(G)=d$
Let $C$ be the shortest cycle in $G$. We can derive a contradiction if we suppose that $g \geq 2d+2$. Here we are observing a cycle for which there exist two vertices $x$ and $y$ such that $d_C(x,y) \geq d+1$. Because $d$ is defined as the greatest distance between any two vertices in $G$, implies vertices $x$ and $y$ must be connected by some path $P^k$ where $k<d+1$. Otherwise $d=d+1$.
Now we can observe that there exists a concatenation of a path in $C$ and $P$ which forms a shorter cycle $xPyCx$ of length at least $2d+1$. Thus a contradiction. Right?

What does $g(G)$ mean?

The minimum length of a cycle contained in a graph G is the girth g(G) of G.

This proof is discussed in more detail here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4639797/clarification-of-proof-that-every-graph-g-containing-a-cycle-satisfies-gg/4639818#4639818 Does that post address your question as well? (It's unclear what your question actually is.)
